# Unable to Concatenate many rows into a single text string sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, string-aggregation

Is there another way to do this without the XML function? I've tried following [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string#545672) 
I'm having issues trying to run this on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int.

```
Select distinct ST2.id 
    substring(
        (
            Select ','+ST1.id AS [text()]
            From dbo.idstable ST1
            Where ST1.id = ST2.id
            ORDER BY ST1.id
            For XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000) [idstable]
From dbo.idstable ST2
```

Comment: What are the data types?  Of id especially....

Comment: just edited this. Data type is int

Comment: INTs need to be CAST to nvarchar...As in answer by @Dan Guzman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the syntax error is the extraneous column name after `DISTINCT`. Below is a similar method that uses `STUFF` and `TYPE` to avoid issues with special characters in the string.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    STUFF(
        (
            SELECT ','+CAST(ST1.id AS varchar(10)) AS [text()]
            FROM dbo.idstable ST1
            WHERE ST1.id = ST2.id
            ORDER BY ST1.id
            FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') [Students]
FROM dbo.idstable ST2;
```

The other supported method for aggregate string concatenation on older SQL versions is a cursor.

Comment: thanks i'll try this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use a cursor as I need this to build a persistent derived table in looker BI tool and the cursor functionality doesn't work.

Comment: @Sql_Pete_Belfast, actually it's probably a good thing you can't use cursors :-)

Comment: Thanks! This is working!

Comment: @Sql_Pete_Belfast, glad to help. Don't forget to mark this as the answer so that others with similar questions can find the solution easier.

Answer (score 1):

Dan's answer is correct, as far as it goes.  From a performance perspective, it is better to do the `distinct` in a subquery (and probably to include the `id` in the outer query:

```
SELECT id
       STUFF( (SELECT ',' + CAST(ST1.id AS varchar(10)) AS [text()]
               FROM dbo.idstable ST1
               WHERE ST1.id = ST2.id
               ORDER BY ST1.id
               FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
              ).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)'
                     ), 1, 1, '') as [Students]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id dbo.idstable) ST2;
```